# L'expression « basé sur » est elle correcte ?

Tags: expressions

J'ai un vague souvenir d'un professeur de français qui m'avait corrigé quant à l'utilisation de l'expression « basé sur », pourtant c'est une expression largement utilisée. 
Ce professeur me faisait remarquer qu'il fallait utiliser « basé » pour décrire un lieu ou une base, par exemple « basé en France ».

J'ai pris l'habitude de ne pas l'utiliser et je remarque à chaque fois que quelqu'un l'utilise. Le site du [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bas%C3%A9) propose des exemples d'auteurs qui utilisent cette expression.

Cette tournure est-elle vraiment correcte ou mon souvenir est trompeur et qu'il y avait un contexte particulier ?

Comment: Dans quel contexte [as-tu](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie) utilisé « Basé sur » ?

Comment: Est-ce que le "basé sur" qui cause problème est celui qu'on met en début de phrase ("Basé sur ces données, je dirais que...") ou simplement un adjectif "un systèmes basé sur des faits"?

Comment: @Benoit je suis désolé pour le délai de réponse. Le « basé sur » qui me pose problème est par exemple « le document d'architecture est basé sur la spécification des besoins ».

Comment: @Circeus il me semble que toutes les formes sont visées.

Comment: @Circeus le premier exemple qui me vient à l'esprit pourrait-être « un logiciel basé sur les technologies Java ».

Comment: Il y a des usages de "basé sur" qui me choquent ou qui sonnent mal à l'oreille, cela dépend du contexte, et l'on peut penser que le professeur, pour prévenir, préfère s'en tenir aux références de base. Cela dénoterait un pauvreté de vocabulaire, une mode mercantile, une référence à un groupe ou surtout une juxtaposition mal jointée. En fait, la gène dépend du sens que l'on retient pour la base et de ce que l'on veut déposer au dessus.

Comment: «le document d'architecture est basé sur la spécification des besoins»: what is it supposed to mean, exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

À mon avis, c'est une approche puriste que j'ai vue référée comme « logicienne », soit l'idée que les mot ne peuvent avoir qu'un sens et qu'il faut éviter les synonymes ([« The general idea seems to be that if there are two words with overlapping meanings, they should be redefined so as to eliminate the overlap. »](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2385)).

*Baser* frappe dans le mille sur les deux cas: il inclus deux sens très différents (car *base* a plusieurs sens différents), et l'un entre en concurrence avec un autre mot, plus ancien, qui plus est (donc plus prestigieux). Bref, c'est du purisme mal placé, voire malavisé, car ce qui fait (à mon avis) toute la richesse d'une langue, ce sont bien ses synonymes! Notons au passage plusieurs autres verbes de sens similaire, certains pouvant être utilisés dans les mêmes constructions: asseoir, appuyer, reposer...

Pour couvrir l'ensemble des possibilités que j'ai notées dans mon commentaire initial, *basé sur* en début de phrase (« Basé sur ces données, je dirais que... ») ne fonctionne pas, ce qui n'a rien d'exceptionnel: aucun des synonymes que j'ai cités ne s'emploie ainsi! Cette construction se réfère au locuteur plutôt qu'à l'object, ce qui n'est vraiment possible avec ce participe passé. Elle devrait s'écrire quelque chose comme « En se basant sur... » ou avec une tout autre construction telle que « d'après » ou « selon ».

Comment: Donc les expressions qui utilisent « basé sur » sont correctes.

Comment: Sous forme d'adjectifs, oui.

Answer (score 7):

L'[Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/baser) déclare que « ce verbe ne doit pas être employé au sens figuré. Il faut lui préférer Fonder, établir. » mais le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baser) signale que une utilisation de cette acception en 1787. Si je me base sur mes observations, l'Académie est bien en retard sur l'usage ici.

Comment: "l'Académie est bien en retard sur l'usage ici." Quiconque aime à consulter Grevisse peut confirmer qu'elle est plus souvent en retard qu'à jour.

Comment: L'utilisation de 1787 remet-elle en cause la règle de l'académie ?

Comment: La présence même de la note le condamnant dans l'entrée du dictionnaire de l'Académie montre qu'il s'agit d'un usage relativement commun.

Answer (score 1):

Je me souviens que mon ancienne prof de français, excellente par ailleurs, nous avait expliqué qu'on ne pouvait pas dire « basé sur » puisque, par définition, il n'y a rien sous une base. Elle est le fondement le plus inférieur, le socle..

Une chose peut être fondée sur quelque chose mais pas basée sur ...