# Accord avec basé

Tags: accord, participe-passé

> Je te remercie pour toute sorte de retour, en particulier sur le volet enseignement, basé sur ta grande expérience.
>
> Je te remercie pour toute sorte de retour, en particulier sur le volet enseignement, basé**e** sur ta grande expérience.

Je me demande si l'accord doit se faire avec retour (masculin donc basé) ou avec sorte (féminin donc basée).

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui est basé, le retour ou la sorte ? Les choses seraient plus claires si "en particulier sur le volet enseignement" n’était pas au milieu, non ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mieux est d'éviter *[basé sur](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2222/lexpression-bas%C3%A9-sur-est-elle-correcte)* qui peut [parfois déplaire](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/base-sur) mais surtout qui n'est pas bien choisi ici car on ne sait pas trop ce qui est basé sur quoi.

Voici une proposition un peu remaniée :

> Je te remercie d'avance pour tout retour, en particulier sur le volet enseignement, au vu de ta grande expérience.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a de nombreux problèmes, pas seulement celui de l'accord de « basé ».

Tout d'abord la tournure a quelque chose de gauche :  l'apposition « basé(e) sur ta grande expérience » doit se trouver près du terme auquel elle est apposée sinon on ne fait pas une connexion rapide ; cela ne signifie pas qu'un terme en apposition doit toujours être placé directement après le terme qu'il complète : il peut être séparé par d'autres élément de la phrase lorsqu'il n'y a pas d'ambiguïté possible ; dans le cas présent non seulement on n'est pas sûr s'il s'agit de « sorte » ou de « retour » mais en plus on peut se demander si « enseignement » ne serait pas le terme en question.

> Je te remercie pour toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s), basée sur ta grande expérience, en particulier sur le volet enseignement.

Lorsque ce changement a été fait, le style reste lourd, diffus: il y a deux qualifications à la suite l'une de l'autre et on ne sait pas immédiatement, ou même pas du tout, si la seconde porte sur le terme modifié par l'apposition ou seulement sur le terme (toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s)). Il y a deux utilisations de « sur » très rapprochées aussi ce qui n'aide pas à la clarté. Une possibilité rendant cela plus lisible est celle qui consiste faire deux phrases ;

> Je te remercie pour toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s), basé(e) sur ta grande expérience ; en particulier je te remercie pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

Cela n'est toujours pas d'un style vraiment acceptable : il est difficile de dire pourquoi ; on peut changer l'apposition en une épithète mais on n'apporte pas d'amélioration : dans ce cas le style est bancal au vu d'une trop grande spécificité ;

> Je te remercie pour toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s) basé(e) sur ta grande expérience ;  en particulier je te remercie pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

Tout cela indique qu'il faut organiser les idées et ne pas essayer d'en dire trop trop vite et sans les formuler proprement. La reconnaissance que les retours sont basés sur une grande expérience peut, non pas être connectée directement à l'autre idée, mais ajoutée en explication, en caractérisation, ou, dit autrement, en description.

En termes de grammaire, au lieu d'utiliser une tournure déterminative (épithète) on peut utiliser une tournure descriptive et cela rétablit l'équilibre dans l'articulation des idées.

> Je te remercie pour toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s), que je sais basé(e) sur ta grande expérience ;  en particulier je te remercie pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

Il y a maintenant un problème avec la forme de l'expression « toute(s) sorte(s) de retour(s) ».

Il faudrait écrire  « toute**s** sorte**s** de retour**s** », cela parce que -- dans le présent contexte --  on fait référence dans la forme plurielle à *une certaine variété de retours **acquis*** et non, comme dans la forme au singulier, à l'éventualité de *n'importe quelle sorte de retour **à venir*** ; dans cette phrase on pourrait arguer que les deux contextes sont possibles, mais le complément « basé(e) sur ta grande expérience » laisse à penser que l'auteur de la phrase a déduit l'existence d'une grande expérience à partir de retours eux-mêmes, donc qu'il remercie pour ces retours et non pour des retours à venir.

> Je te remercie pour toutes sortes de retours, que je sais basé(e) sur ta grande expérience ;  en particulier je te remercie pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

Apparemment, il ne reste plus qu'à prendre soin de l'accord du mot « basé » ; on a le choix, et si dans la langue parlée il est quasiment sans importance, dans la langue écrite il peut en avoir, mais pas dans le cas présent parce que « toutes sortes » n'est qu'un terme qui sert à stipuler qu'il s'agit d'une grande variété de retours et ce qui compte vraiment c'est le concept de retour ; il est tout indiqué d'écrire « basés » en l'accordant avec « retours ».

> Je te remercie pour toutes sortes de retours, que je sais basés sur ta grande expérience ;  en particulier je te remercie pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

(Cela signifie, cependant que les remerciements s'appliquent à de nombreux retours mais pas à tous.)

*Variantes pour laquelle tous les retours sont inclus dans les remerciements*

> Je te remercie pour tes retours de toutes sortes, que je reconnais comme basés sur une grande expérience, mais tout particulièrement pour ceux relatifs au volet enseignement.

Answer (score 1):

Weird sentence in general, this use of retour is strange.

But that said of course you'd use basé, there's no way this would apply to experience, the only feminine word in that sentence